# how to navigate directory in executable batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I write a sample script

my current directory is in C:/.../cleanup/bin
I want to assign cleanup/logs to variable $log which seemed to have failed.

```
echo Current Directory = %CD%

$log = "%CD%\..\logs 
pushd %log%
echo Current directory = %CD%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "log=%CD%\..\logs" & pushd %log% & echo Current directory = %CD%
```

- Use `set` to assign variables
- Don't add spaces around `=`
- %CD% doesn't have a trailing `\` for folders so add it manually
- Use `&` to concatenate several commands on one line
- Use surrounding quotes in `set` to omit trailing spaces before the next `&` if it's present